# Maximise $x^T Ax$ for A symmetric s.t. $x^Tx=1$ and $x$ lies in a finite set of unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations

> Given a symmetric matrix $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$,
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \mathrm x^T \mathrm A \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm x^T \mathrm x = 1\\ & \mathrm x \in S\end{array}$$
>
> where $S$ is a *finite* set of unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

---

We could try calculating $x^TAx$ for every $x$ in $S$, but suppose that is computationally too slow. So I want to find an alternative method to get to an optimum. I know that if x could be any unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, we could choose x to be any unit vectors in the eigenspace corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of A. Would choosing the closest point to this eigenspace from our set $S$ give us an optimal for this problem? I would really appreciate some references to some papers/ theorems which explores this idea. Thanks.

Comment: Your setting is unclear, in my opinion. E.g., if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, why does "$x$ lie in a finite dimensional subspace"? Please, explain what the objects are a bit better.

Comment: I have just clarified and corrected my original question- please remove hold. Thank you.

Comment: How are your finite number (say $N$) of points given? If they are simply listed, there is little hope of doing anything optimal over those points in less than $O(dN)$ time, so why do you consider computing $N$ scalar products computationally slow? (It is $O(d^2N)$ but I suppose $d$ is not huge.) Choosing the closest point to a subspace would suffer from the same difficulty.